# Traefik v2: 404 while routing HTTP traffic globally to HTTPS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I have the problem that I can route HTTPS traffic but I can not globally redirect the HTTP traffic to HTTPS. In my case I only want HTTPS traffic, so that I want to redirect all the incoming traffic.

Currently I get an 404 error while I try to serve my URLs over HTTP.
I already enabled DEBUG logs in Treafik, but I can not see any problems or unnormal stuff in the logs.

Additionally I saw a pretty similar topic here on Stackoverflow, but we found out, that his error was not the same to mine: [How to redirect http to https with Traefik 2.0 and Docker Compose labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356714/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-with-traefik-2-0-and-docker-compose-labels)

The following setup is based on the blog entry here: https://blog.containo.us/traefik-2-0-docker-101-fc2893944b9d

**My setup**

I configured Traefik in my swarm like this:

```
global:
  checkNewVersion: false
  sendAnonymousUsage: false
api:
  dashboard: true
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
  websecure:
    address: :443
providers:
  providersThrottleDuration: 2s
docker:
  watch: true
  endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  swarmMode: true
  swarmModeRefreshSeconds: 15s
  exposedByDefault: false
  network: webgateway
log:
  level: DEBUG
accessLog: {}
certificatesResolvers:
  default:
    acme:
    email: {email}
    storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
    httpChallenge:
      entryPoint: web
```

And started Traefik with the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /data/docker_data/traefik/traefik-2.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    - /data/docker_data/traefik/acme-2.json:/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
    labels:
    # redirect
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
    - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.entrypoints=web"
    - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
```

My services are configured with the following labels:

```
traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`myapp.ch`)
traefik.http.routers.myapp.service=myapp
traefik.http.routers.myapp.entrypoints=websecure
# I don't think that the following one is required here...
# traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls.certresolver=default
traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.server.port=3000
traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls=true
traefik.enable=true
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect http to https with Traefik 2.0 and Docker Compose labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356714/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-with-traefik-2-0-and-docker-compose-labels)

Comment: With the answer from Lars, yes.
But with his configuration I could not solve it globally, but I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to configure the Traefik service itself. On Traefik you only need to have entrypoints to :443 (websecure) and :80 (web)

Because Traefik only acts as entryPoint and will not do the redirect, the middleware on the target service will do that.

Now configure your target service as the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mywebserver:
    image: 'httpd:alpine'
    container_name: mywebserver
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.mywebserver-redirect-websecure.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.routers.mywebserver-web.middlewares=mywebserver-redirect-websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.mywebserver-web.rule=Host(`sub.domain.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.mywebserver-web.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.mywebserver-websecure.rule=Host(`sub.domain.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.mywebserver-websecure.tls.certresolver=mytlschallenge
      - traefik.http.routers.mywebserver-websecure.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.mywebserver-websecure.entrypoints=websecure
      # if you have multiple ports exposed on the service, specify port in the websecure service
      - traefik.http.services.mywebserver-websecure.loadbalancer.server.port=9000
```

So basically the flow goes like this:

Request: http://sub.domain.com:80 --> traefik (service) --> mywebserver-web (router, http rule) --> mywebserver-redirect-websecure (middleware, redirect to https) --> mywebserver-websecure (router, https rule) --> mywebserver (service)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lars.
I tried it and `yey` I was successful. Thank you so much.
But: When I read your answer again. Is it in Traefik v2 not possible to create a global redirect?
Anyway I am interested in your answer but I will set this question as solved.

Comment: I have not figured it out to do it globally. I don't think it's possible at the moment... :)

Comment: It is not possible at the moment. They are aware of this / want to improve this. https://community.containo.us/t/a-global-http-https-redirection/864/7

Comment: Also, workaround: https://community.containo.us/t/global-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-https-redirection/2313/6?u=zespri

Answer (score 6):

This is for those who are trying Global HTTP to HTTPS redirection on Traefik 2. Some of you might be getting 404 on the http endpoints. After literal hours spending on the different forums. This works for me. This applies for people who want to use pre-signed ssl certificates as well.

As most of us are using config provided in the traefik blogs and many dont contain the command section of traefik container where we declared for security purpose

`"--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"`

This prevents the global https redirector to work if we dont give

`"traefik.enable=true"`

here is the full file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2.1"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.watch=true"
      - "--providers.file.directory=/conf/"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - somenetwork
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - ./certs:/certs
      - ./conf:/conf
    labels:
      # this is needed as we did the --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      # global redirect to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    networks:
      - somenetwork
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.rule=Host(`test.traefik.localhost`)"
```

I am also adding the `certificates.toml` inside conf directory. If you are working on localhost then you can add this using mkcert openssl etc. For production you need to need to get this from certificate providers. And you need to add the certificates in the certs folder.

```
[[tls.certificates]] #first certificate
   certFile = "/certs/_wildcard.traefik.localhost.pem"
   keyFile = "/certs/_wildcard.traefik.localhost-key.pem"
```

And of course you can use lets encrypt. There are a lot of blogs on that topic.

Hope this saves your times. :)

Comment: Thank you! At first I almost dismissed your comment as I already had traefik.enable=true on the webapp, but then realised you meant on the actual traefik container too!